# The roots of the equation $(a^4+b^4)x^2+4abcd x + (c^4+d^4)$will be?

Tags: quadratics

The discriminant shall be 
$$16(abcd)^2-4a^4c^4-4a^4d^4-4b^4c^4-4b^4d^4$$
$$-4(b^2d^2+a^2c^2)^2-4(a^2d^2+b^2d^2)^2$$ which is clearly a negative value. So the roots should be imaginary. But the answer given is real and equal. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It will be $$-4(a^2b^2-c^2d^2)^2-4(a^2d^2-b^2c^2)^2\le0$$

Comment: Why? Since the square will will always be positive and multiplied by a negative 4, the value will be negative

Comment: @Aditya, Sorry for the typo

Comment: Okay, so the roots will still be imaginary right?

Comment: @Aditya, unless both perfect squares are $0$

Answer (score 1):

Your discriminant is written slightly wrong it should be 
$$-4(b^2d^2 - a^2c^2)^2 -4(a^2d^2 - b^2c^2)^2.$$
Further as per the equation you have written you are surely   correct that it will have imaginary roots. May be the answer given is wrong or some more information may be provided. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant is given by $$-a^4c^4-a^4d^4+4a^2b^2c^2d^2-b^4c^4-b^4a^4$$ and now completing the squares.